# How do i plot a square wave in Desmos

Tags: fourier-series, desmos

I'm studying Fourier series and i'm using Desmos to graph the results and it does look like its approximating towards a square wave

but is there a way that i can just graph a square wave in desmos? and periodic functions in general?

Comment: Does $(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}$ work?

Comment: Smth like this is Ok: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMOkx.png

Comment: And $\frac{|\sin(\pi x)|}{\sin(\pi x)}$, does work? (if we define the function to be 0 at $x \in \mathbb{N}$)

Answer (score 1):

$\sin(\pi\lfloor x \rfloor +\frac{\pi}{2})$ should do the trick.

More generally, a $\sin(\pi(\lfloor bx+c \rfloor+\frac{\pi}{2})+d$. Modify $c$ and $d$ to translate, modify $a$ and $b$ to scale.

Answer (score 0):

One way is:

$$(A_p-A_m)\operatorname{round}(\operatorname{mod}(fx,1))+A_m$$

where the function jumps between $A_p$ and $A_m$, the frequency is $f$, and the amplitude is $A=|A_p-A_m|$.

- [Desmos plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bye2fzxpnk)